# How to create configuration files that contain colons in YAML?

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, gitlab-ci

According to [CI's lint](https://gitlab.com/ci/lint), this yml is not valid:

```
pages:
  stage: deploy
  image: python:3.5
  script:
  - echo "foo: $VAR" > site.yml
  - cat ~/.python-gitlab.cfg

  artifacts:
    paths:
      - _build
  only:
    - master
```

error:

```
jobs:pages:script config should be a string or an array of strings
```

If I remove the colon on the `echo` line, it works.

What I want to do is to create some configuration files on the fly, to comply to existing tools, using private variables, like `echo "url: $CI_PROJECT_URL" > site.yml` to produce

```
url: "https://gitlab.com/group/project"
```

But I can't do this because the yaml is said invalid, and I don't find workarounds. Or I must write code around my tools to pass command line arguments instead of reading config files. Still, this colon stuff seems a bug.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It should work if you wrap the whole line within quotes like this:

```
- 'echo "foo: $VAR" > site.yml'
```

Gitlab's CI lint marks it as correct syntax.

See [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/30097) for more info.

Answer (score 8):

Single quotes around the whole line, as depicted by @Jawad, works:

> ```
> - 'echo "foo: $VAR" > site.yml'
> ```

But if your command contains other single quotes, I find it easiest to use the `pipe` Block Scaler Style: `|`

```
- |
  echo "I want to echo the key"
  echo 'foo: $VAR' > site.yml
```

More documentation on Block Scaler Styles can be found here: http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2760844

Comment: This is a neat trick. However, it does have the side effect that in the output logs, you will only see the first command. The subsequent commands will be replaced with `# collapsed multi-line command`.

Comment: Also, you can simplify to just `script: |`, you don't need the `- |`